# Ruby Gem conflicts between local gem and system installed gem

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I have a Gemfile that looks something like this:

source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gemspec
gem "parent_gem", "0.1.3", :path => "#{File.expand_path(__FILE__)}/../vendor/gems/parent_gem-0.1.3"
```

`parent_gem` depends on `child_gem-1.4.1`, which we have packaged in the `/vender/gems` folder in the package. If a user installs `child_gem-1.6.0` on their host on Ubuntu, they will get a `Gem::ConflictError` because it will try to use 1.6 and log `child_gem-1.6.0 conflicts with child_gem (~> 1.4.1).` However, if a user runs it on Amazon Linux, it works fine and uses the packaged child gem.

If I run `gem list child_gem`, I get the following output on both systems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

child_gem (1.6.1)
```

`gem list parent_gem` returns nothing because it's not installed separated and only exists in the package's `vendor` directory.

In the files that initiates the script, there is this line:

```
Gem.use_paths(nil, Gem.path << "/opt/my-app/vendor")
```

And the `/opt/my-app/vendor` directory includes `child_gem-1.4.1`.

Ultimately, I know that setting up the package properly with Bundler should resolve the issue, but I'm trying to understand why this is an issue.

How does Ruby decide where to look for a gem on a system? And where do I look to understand why it works on Amazon Linux but not Ubuntu?

Comment: Ruby doesn't use Gemfile; Bundler does.

Comment: what gems does your amazon linux box have? do `$ gem list child_gem` and show the output please

Comment: @uDaY I added the output to the question.

Comment: thanks!can you also do the same for the parent_gem and show if you're forcing the child_gem to particular version in Gemfile.